# how to set facebook app id in iOS

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, app-id

I thought an app need to submit the App ID to facebook server to pass OAuth , getting user's permission , then get the active session to read/post information.

I am looking for something like:

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");
```

I checked the "Facebook iOS SDK" tutorials and project "HelloFacebookSample" , but did not find any code to set my App ID. How to set my App ID and App Secret? How to make "HelloFacebookSample" to use my App , instead of using the official sample app?
I am using Xcode. Thanks.

Comment: [Follow this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) I hope this will help.

Comment: I missed something. I should setup it in info.plist file

Answer (score 4):

you should set it in the **Info.plist** just before the last `</dict>` element

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>2.8</string>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{{Your app name}}</string>
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started